# Which aircraft have made notable use of lateral asymmetry?

Tags: aircraft-design

I'm asking about functional asymmetry - doors on one side but not the other wouldn't count.

## Examples

I can think of three examples:

- experiments with oblique wing designs, such as NASA's utterly hideous [AD-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_AD-1), designed apparently by Burt Rutan
- displaced fuselage designs, such as the [Blohm & Voss BV 141](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blohm_%26_Voss_BV_141) or (another Burt Rutan aircraft), the [Boomerang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Boomerang)
- all single-propeller aircraft, in which the torque of the engine exerts asymmetrical forces on the aircraft

## Symmetrical asymmetry doesn't count

(Then there are some that I don't think really count - for example, the Wright brothers' [Flyer 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Flyer) placed the engine and the pilot side-by-side, but since they were intended to balance each other out and the twin propellors were symmetrically placed, that counts as an attempt at symmetry as far as I am concerned!)

## Other examples, and the reason for their asymmetrical design

Are there any other good examples? The more ugly and wrong-looking, the better.

I'm interested in the problems that the asymmetry aimed to solve - for example, oblique wing designs aimed to procure aerodynamic advantages (which turned out to be at the expense of handling issues), or Rutan's Boomerang which "was intended to be a multi-engine aircraft that in the event of failure of a single engine would not become dangerously difficult to control due to asymmetric thrust" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Boomerang))

## Visual reference

Just for reference, here's the AD-1 ([NASA, via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NASA_AD-1_in_flight.jpg)):

[image: NASA AD-1]

... and the BV 141 ([Deutsche Bundesarchiv, via Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Bundesarchiv_Bild_146-1980-117-01%2C_Aufkl%C3%A4rungsflugzeug_Blohm_-_Vo%C3%9F_BV_141.jpg)):

[image: Blohm & Voss BV 141]

Comment: Burt Rutan's [Boomerang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Boomerang) is asymmetrical, but I wouldn't call it ugly.

Comment: 747 with a spare engine mounted...

Comment: The Wright Flyer's wing was 4 inches wider on the side of the engine, because the Wrights wanted to compensate for the heavy engine. Wouldn't that count as a functional asymmetry?

Comment: Don't be silly, why would anyone make an assym... oooh... I learned a thing today!

Comment: @PeterKämpf I didn't know about the wing length, I guess that probably counts!

Comment: Don't know if you found it, but there's actually a short Wikipedia page on [asymmetrical aircraft.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetrical_aircraft)  It also talks briefly about the design considerations involved.

Comment: there are many GA aircraft that have an asymmetrical engine mount and/or an asymmetrical empannage to counter P-factor.

Comment: @rbp: Many propeller-powered fighter aircraft had cambered vertical tails to help counter torque effects. I guess that is also a functional asymmetry, but not ugly or wrong-looking enough to count here.

Comment: Some single-engine fighters of the WWII era had one wing extended to help counter engine torque.

Answer (score 25):

There are quite a few asymmetric aircraft, most of which are,

- experimental
- engine test beds

A good example of experimental aircraft is the NASA F-16XL

[image: F-16XL]

F-16XL with supersonic laminar flow control experiment (black area on left wing, front) or "glove." Image from [nasa.gov](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/langley/news/factsheets/HSR-Wings.html)

Aircraft used as engine test beds are usually asymmetric. The following image shows a B-47 Stratojet used as engine test bed for the the Orenda engine earmarked for Avro Arrow program.

[image: B-47]

Image from [silverhawkauthor.com](http://silverhawkauthor.com/canadian-warbirds-6-jets-and-helicopters-book_313.html)

A closeup of the rear:

[image: B-47]

Image from [google](https://sites.google.com/site/canadair50otherproducts/B47lge.jpg)

[English Electric Canberra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Electric_Canberra) PR9s had offset canopies.

[image: Canberra PR9]

By [MilborneOne](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:MilborneOne) - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=13266605

So did the [de Havilland Sea Vixens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Sea_Vixen).

[image: Sea Vixen]

By [Yeovilton_Vixen_2009-001.tif](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yeovilton_Vixen_2009-001.tif): [Nigel Ish](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Nigel_Ish)derivative work: [Cobatfor](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Cobatfor) - This file was derived from  [Yeovilton Vixen 2009-001.tif](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yeovilton_Vixen_2009-001.tif): , CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=19477903

Of course, all 'conventional' helicopters (with tail rotors on one side) are asymmetric, but I don't think that's what you're after here.

Also, see [this page](http://www.kristofmeunier.fr/Asymm_addition.htm) and the [Wikipedia page on asymmetric aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetrical_aircraft). As a disclaimer, I wouldn't call any of these aircraft 'ugly'.

Comment: I have never seen or heard of most of these aircraft! This is fascinating. +1 for the great question and +1 for this great answer.

Comment: The Orenda ingests the boundary layer of the wing in the configuration used on the B-47! What were they thinking? This is no way to conduct proper testing.

Comment: If we count aircraft with offset parts then there are probably more aircraft than one might expect. Even the A-10 has an offset nose landing gear in order to accommodate the gun.https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8722/16696627519_9142f36d14_b.jpg

Comment: The observer in the Sea Vixen was positioned under the hatch to the right of the offset cockpit canopy; this was a frangible hatch where the ejection seat would shatter the hatch in the event of an ejection. Unfortunately, it was not always as frangible as it should have been.

Answer (score 5):

All aircraft with external storage that dump only one become instantly asymmetrical. A particularly extreme example might be the Heinkel He-111 H22, which was designed to carry a V1 to a launching point in order to attack targets beyond the reach of the fixed launch catapults, or the B-52 used to carry the X-15 aloft.

[image: Heinkel He-111 H22 with FZG-76]

Heinkel He-111 H22 with FZG-76 (picture [source](http://en.valka.cz/attachments/121/He_111_H-22.jpg))

Even after dropping the cruise missile, the He-111 H remained an asymmetrical configuration, because the tip of its glazed nose was offset to one side, so the front gunner would obstruct the pilot's view less.

[image: Inside view of the He-111 cockpit]

Inside view of the He-111 cockpit (picture [source](http://www.historyofwar.org/Pictures/he_111_cable_cutter2.jpg)).

[image: B-52 just after launch of the X-15]

B-52 just after launch of the X-15 (picture [source](http://media-1.web.britannica.com/eb-media/12/65012-120-CA2E5A36.jpg))

Also here the aircraft remained asymmetrical after having launched the X-15 due to the [large pylon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21370/why-does-this-b-52-carry-a-payload-only-on-its-right-wing) used for carrying the X-15.

Answer (score 4):

Another Rutan design (I think his earliest asymmetric) was the [Ares "mudfighter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_ARES) with a 25mm cannon on one side of the cockpit, and the turbojet air intake on the other. The design was intended to keep the pressure waves and nasty combustion gasses from the cannon from being ingested by the engine.

The [NASA X-15 Active](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/history/pastprojects/Active/index.html) wasn't asymmetric by design, but was designed to *induce* asymmetries (to simulate failures, or damage, up to and including loss of an entire wing).

Answer (score 4):

The M.C.202 actually had wings of different sizes to compensate the engine/propeller rotation:

As rightfully requested, here are some pictures from the video:

[image: M.C.202 from top]

[image: M.C. 202 from bottom, mirrored left wing]

[image: M.C. 202 from bottom, difference made clear]

Comment: Many fighter aircraft of that period had cambered vertical tails to help to counter torque effects. This is also a functional asymmetry.

Answer (score 3):

The Rutan Voyager (World Flight, 1986) two wings are not at the same position along the length of the aircraft. To save weight, their non-tapered spars are bolted together in the fuselage, so one wing is one spar thickness ahead of the other. With a wingspan of over 100 feet, it isn't very noticeable.

It also has two vertical stabilizers but only the starboard one has a movable rudder. To cut down on questions about that, they put a line on the port one that looks like a rudder gap using an ink marker (lighter than paint!). Lower cruise drag and weight at the cost of terrible rudder performance asymmetry (right rudder response was fine; left rudder response almost nonexistent).

This learned from conversations with Dick Rutan, the Voyager's pilot, in 1985/1986.